# difference between continue and continue with

Tags: word-choice

> Though it was very late, they **continued** their discussion.

I interpret **continue** as “keep discussing without stopping”.

Can I use **continue with** interchangeably?

Answer (score 2):

To **continue** *something* is to keep doing it or to resume doing it. The activity is not terminated but prolonged.

> They **continued their discussion** long into the night.
>
> They **continued their hike** around the mountain lake after stopping for a brief rest.

To **continue with** *something* is to not change or alter it in response to conditions, but to proceed with it, as before. The complement of **with** in this pattern will be some sort of undertaking which is *instrumental* in achieving a result or goal of some kind.

> The sky began to get gray, but the weather app said only light showers were expected, so they **continued with their plans** to have a picnic later that afternoon.
>
> Notwithstanding the opposition they encountered from the National Rifle Association, the students **continued with their efforts** to ban the sale of military assault weapons.

Comment: From your examples, I feel that “continue” is followed by a specific activity people were doing before, while “continue with” is followed by something that doesn’t tell what specific activities people were doing before. Can I still say “Let’s continue with the discussion”? If so, how do you understand it?

Comment: The relevant difference between **discussion|hike** and **plans|efforts** is not one of specificity versus inspecificity.  That which is **continued with** is not *prolonged* or *reinitiated*.